# Evaluating infinite series of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac {N-1} {N}\right)^k \frac {10^k} {k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having some trouble evaluating the infinite series given by

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac {N-1} {N}\right)^k \frac {10^k} {k!}
$$

Immediately at first glance, I recognize that the expression resembles a 'product' of an infinite geometric series involving $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac {N-1} {N}\right)^k$ as well as the Maclaurin series of $e^{10} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {10^k} {k!}$. However, I find myself lost when putting those two inner expressions together in a single summation. Running the expression through SageMath gives

$$
e^{\left(-\frac {10} {N} + 10\right)}
$$

I apologize if I am overlooking something basic, as this was encountered in a text for an undergraduate probability course. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{N-1}{N}\right)^k 10^k = \left(\frac{10(N-1)}{N}\right)^k.$$